# Balance doesn't change after I mint NFT

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, balances, mint

I am trying to connect EC2 with my testnet CA which I deployed on Mumbai.
The Contract is a functions as an NFT, inheriting ERC721.sol from @openzeppelin.
I created my Instance in aws EC2, and I wrote main.js which has info about CA & ABI I deployed on Mumbai. Then I use Postman to send GET & POST requests to call functions of CA connected to main.js.
The problem I have is, after I mint simple NFT with POST request, I send GET request to get my balance(which must be +1 after I minted), but the balance of my address is still zero. I have no idea how to fix this.

These are my code below:

```
// function mint in myNFT.sol
function mint(
        address _to,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _url,
        string memory _attribute1
    ) public {
        // I used struct to myNFT
        uint _tokenId = myNFTs.length;
        myNFTs.push(
            myNFT(_name, _url, _attribute1)
        );
        _mint(_to, _tokenId);
    }

// the part of main.js that calls the mint function
app.post('/mint', async function(req, res) {
    const _to = req.body.to;
    const _name = req.body.name;
    const _url = req.body.url;
    const _attribute = req.body.attribute;
    try {
        const bytedata = await contract.methods.mint(_to, _name, _url, _attirubte).encodeABI();
        const mintTx = {
            from: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
            to: _to,
            gas: 1000000,
            gasPrice: '21000000000',
            data: bytedata
        };
        const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.mintTx, PRIV_KEY);
        const sentTx = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send({ error: err.toString() });
    }
})

// This is the body part of the POST request I made in postman
// requested url: my-ec2-public-ipv4:3000/mint
{
    "to": "0xF806711dfa8193F860EBBcEfCEa6DF0665903f16",
    "name": "name",
    "url": "123",
    "attribute": "attribute"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors that I see.

1. The line `const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.mintTx, PRIV_KEY);` looks like a typo or error. The method `web3.eth.accounts.mintTx` does not exist in the Web3.js library. You're probably intending to sign the transaction before sending it, which should be done with the `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction` method.
2. the `to:` field in your mintTx object is set to `_to.` This should be set to the contract address because you are calling a method (`mint`) on the contract, not sending Ether to `_to`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!